# How to get the dictionary name for each key with the highest value across multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I have a unique list of names called `AllNames` and several sub-lists where these names can be repeated, or not be found at all. For example

```
AllNames = ['John', 'Mark', 'Tony', 'Bob', 'Jack']

blue = ['John', 'John', 'Mark', 'Jack']
green = ['Mark', 'Mark', 'Jack']
red = ['Bob', 'Jack']
# These are dictionaries with the counts for each list
blueCounter = Counter({'John': 2, 'Mark': 1, 'Jack': 1})
greenCounter = Counter({'Mark': 2, 'Jack': 1})
redCounter = Counter({'Bob': 1, 'Jack': 1})
```

For each `name` in `AllNames` I want to get the name of the list which has the highest count for `name` and put it in a new list. Based on the above, I would get:

```
blueList = ['John'] # since John has the highest count across all lists
greenList = ['Mark']
redList =['Bob']
```

Note that for `'Jack'`, who is found an equal number of times in all three lists, I don't want his name to appear anywhere. Similarly `'Tony'`, whose name doesn't appear in any list, should not be included.

I am trying to apply `stats.iteritems` but this gets the highest value in one dictionary.

**EDIT: Another example**

```
a=['John', 'John', 'John', 'Mark', 'Mark', 'Mark', 'Joe']
b= ['John', 'Mark', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Jack']
c= ['Mark', 'Joe', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Tony']

ac = Counter(a)
bc = Counter(b)
cc = Counter(c)

# >>> ac
# Counter({'John': 3, 'Mark': 3, 'Joe': 1})
# >>> bc
# Counter({'Joe': 3, 'Jack': 1, 'John': 1, 'Mark': 1})
# >>> cc
# Counter({'Jack': 2, 'Tony': 1, 'Joe': 1, 'Mark': 1})
```

The result should be:

```
alist = ['John', 'Mark']
blist = ['Joe']
clist = ['Jack', 'Tony']
```

Comment: Start by putting the sublists into a dictionary. Your title suggests you have one but I don't see any dictionaries in your actual question.

Comment: I added the Counter dictionaries for each list separately. But I was wondering if these counters should be placed in a main dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

a=['John', 'John', 'John', 'Mark', 'Mark', 'Mark', 'Joe']
b= ['John', 'Mark', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Jack']
c= ['Mark', 'Joe', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Tony']

ac = Counter(a)
bc = Counter(b)
cc = Counter(c)


allLists = [list(), list(), list()]

allNames = set(ac.keys() + bc.keys() + cc.keys());

for name in allNames:

    aCount = ac[name];
    bCount = bc[name];
    cCount = cc[name];

    allCounts = np.array([aCount, bCount, cCount]);

    maxIndex = allCounts.argsort()[::-1][0];

    allLists[maxIndex] += [name];


alist, blist, clist = allLists[:]

print alist, blist, clist
```

Comment: Thanks this is just what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
from collections import Counter

AllNames = ['John', 'Mark', 'Tony', 'Bob', 'Jack']

blue = ['John', 'John', 'Mark', 'Jack']
green = ['Mark', 'Mark', 'Jack']
red = ['Bob', 'Jack']

# These are dictionaries with the counts for each list
blueCounter = Counter({'John': 2, 'Mark': 1, 'Jack': 1})
greenCounter = Counter({'Mark': 2, 'Jack': 1})
redCounter = Counter({'Bob': 1, 'Jack': 1})

names = []
for counter in blueCounter, greenCounter, redCounter:
    name_with_highest_count = counter.most_common()[0][0]
    if name_with_highest_count in AllNames:
        names.append([name_with_highest_count])

blueList, greenList, redList = names

print(blueList)  # -> ['John']
print(greenList) # -> ['Mark']
print(redList)   # -> ['Bob']
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I just need a small clarification. How are the ``names`` separated into the ``blueList``, ``greenList``, and ``redList`` if they are all in the same list ``names``? Sorry i'm relatively new to Python.

Comment: Since it appears you want the names each to be put into a list, I make `names` a list of lists by using `names.append([name_with_highest_count])` to add each one instead of `names.append(name_with_highest_count)`.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry missed that detail. Thanks again!

Comment: Note: @DeepSpace is probably right about not needing `AllNames`. You could eliminate it and just unconditionally `append` the most common name in the `for` loop.

Comment: I had another try on my data set, the for loop only gets the key of the highest value in each dictionary. Instead, I want, for each key in the union of all dictionaries, the name of the dictionary where that key has the highest value.

Comment: I did not change the question. It is the same, I just gave an additional example because i just thought I got the right answer but i was mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need `AllNames`:

```
from collections import Counter

lists = { 'blue': ['John', 'John', 'Mark', 'Jack'], 'green': ['Mark', 'Mark', 'Jack'], 'red': ['Bob', 'Jack']}

for li in lists:
    print li, Counter(lists[li]).most_common()[0]

>> blue ('John', 2)
   green ('Mark', 2)
   red ('Bob', 1)
```

If you want to create a dictionary from list name to the most common name simply do:

```
most_common_dict = {}
for li in lists:
    most_common_dict[li] = Counter(lists[li]).most_common()[0][0]
>>  {'blue': 'John', 'green': 'Mark', 'red': 'Bob'}
```

Or in 1 line if you're using `Python 2.7` or above:

```
most_common_dict = { li: Counter(lists[li]).most_common()[0][0] for li in lists }
```

Comment: This method also gives only the most common key in each list. Instead i want, for each key in the union of all three lists, the name of the list which has the highest value for that key.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comment under my [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31707225/355230), you have changed the question. Besides that, it now doesn't make sense to have 3 explicitly named result lists — `alist`, `blist`, and `clist` — and to also give "for each key in the union of all dictionaries, the name of the dictionary where that key has the highest value".

The latter quoted part means there could be a dictionary name for each of the keys and since there's at total of than 3 keys, there could be more than 3 "results".

Here's an attempt to ignore that inconsistency and implement what you said in the quote:

```
from collections import Counter

a = ['John', 'John', 'John', 'Mark', 'Mark', 'Mark', 'Joe']
b = ['John', 'Mark', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Jack']
c = ['Mark', 'Joe', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Tony']

ac = Counter(a)
bc = Counter(b)
cc = Counter(c)

print('ac: {}'.format(ac))
print('bc: {}'.format(bc))
print('cc: {}'.format(cc))
print('')

key_dict = {}  # maps key to name of dictionary where it has highest value

for key in set(a+b+c):  # set(a+b+c) == all keys
    highest_dict_name, highest_value = None, -1

    for dict_name, counter in (('ac', ac), ('bc', bc), ('cc', cc)):
        s = set(counter.values())
        d = {j : [i for i in counter if counter[i] == j] for j in s}
        highest_item = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i: i[0])[-1]
        if (highest_item[0] > highest_value and
            key in highest_item[1]):
            highest_dict_name, highest_value = dict_name, highest_item[0]

    key_dict[key] = highest_dict_name

print('For each key, dictionary were it has highest value:')
for key in sorted(key_dict):
    print('  {!r} in {!r}'.format(key, key_dict[key]))
```

Output:

```
ac: Counter({'John': 3, 'Mark': 3, 'Joe': 1})
bc: Counter({'Joe': 3, 'Jack': 1, 'John': 1, 'Mark': 1})
cc: Counter({'Jack': 2, 'Tony': 1, 'Joe': 1, 'Mark': 1})

For each key, dictionary were it has highest value:
  'Jack' in 'cc'
  'Joe' in 'bc'
  'John' in 'ac'
  'Mark' in 'ac'
  'Tony' in None
```